# Copy csv file into different schema

Tags: postgresql, permissions, import, csv

I need to import data from a csv file  which from database a schema a into another database b schema b.

I used the pgAdmin running the export and when I import the data using the same tool pgAdmin and/or directly from psql prompt, I get an error:

> permission denied for schema a

both tables from schema a and schema b are the same information definition and attributes.  Not even csv from Oracle's table.

Just a csv, do I still needs to specify schema to schema and how?

```
"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\pgAdmin 4\\v4\\runtime\\psql.exe" --command " "\\copy b.sc_g28 (receipt_number, rep_ins_attny_id, rep_state_num, rep_volag, rep_rep_code, rep_last_name, rep_first_name, rep_middle_name, rep_firm_name, rep_street, rep_street_2, rep_city, rep_state, rep_zip, rep_province, rep_postal_code, rep_country, mig_filename, mig_insert_dt, mig_modified_dt) FROM 'C:/cidr/CIDR_D~1/EXP_SC~1.CSV' CSV HEADER QUOTE '\"' ESCAPE
ERROR:  permission denied for schema a
```

---

- There is a trigger on both a.sc_28 and b.sc_g28.
- I have 2 instances (databases) pscidr and cidr.
- pscidr has 3 schemas and owned by postgres.
- cidr has 3 schemas and each schema owned by each user/role.

I have no problem to export Oracle's table to csv and import to postgres pscidr schema's table without disable constraint but I can't import either one from Oracle's table and/or a.sc_g28 to b.sc_g28 of cidr db.  Keep receive the "permission denied a.sc_g28".  An a.sc_g28 is from pscidr database.

Can't disable the constraint b.sc_g28's pkey or turned deferrable/deferred on from pgAdmin.

```
alter table b.sc_g28 disable constraint sc_g28_pkey;
```

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "constraint" LINE 2: alter table b.sc_g28 disable constraint sc_g28_pkey; ^ SQL state: 42601 Character: 38
```

or

```
ALTER TABLE b.sc_g28 ALTER CONSTRAINT sc_g28_pkey DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;
```

```
ERROR: constraint "sc_g28_pkey" of relation "sc_g28" does not exist SQL state: 42704
```

I try to alter trigger fine without error

```
ALTER TABLE cidrdata.sc_g28 DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;
```

but still can't import csv file into b.sc_g28.

```
ERROR:  permission denied for schema a.
```

Comment: Welcome to DBA.SE. From what I initially understand from your question, you are trying to export a schema from Oracle into a CSV file and import the same schema into a PostgreSQL schema? I don't think that is going to work. If I've been mistaken, then could you please rephrase your question, so that the community can provide you with a solution. Hit [edit] and add missing details or delete unrelated information. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem and fixed it.

I grant usage on table to role/user

> grant usage on schema schema_name to role/user;

Thank you for all input.

Comment: Could you please write up your answer so that those who have a similar problem in future can find a solution? You can also mark your own answer as correct (no points though! :-( ), but it might lead to future points as correct answers rise to the top in searches! p.s. welcome to the forum!